# Should I use a class as a wrapper?

Tags: object-oriented, python, class-design

Lets say I have a class representing a chemical compound

```
class Compound(networkx.Graph): 

    def __init__(self):
        super(Compound, self).__init__()
```

And lets say that I want to add some extra functionality onto a chemical compound.  It should probably inherit from Compound.  But is it okay to just use it as a wrapper for Compound?  For example

```
class Acid(Compound):

    def __init__(self, compound, *other_data):
        self.__dict__.update(compound.__dict__)
```

Basically, this class would just have pointers to the underlying class and then let me add functionality without having to copy things.  Does this make sense?  Is it reasonable? Am I even doing it right?

Comment: You are both inheriting *and* wrapping. If `Acid` is a *kind* of `Compound`, then inherit, not wrap. You don't need to copy things if you inherit; that is kind of the point of inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use inheritance in this case, but wrapping the object you with to extend is fine as well. In fact, the technique is useful enough to have a name: the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

The usual way to forward all calls in Python is not to mess around with `__dict__`, but to override `__getattr__` ("explicit is better than implicit"):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._b = B(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._b, name)
```

`__getattr__` only fires when the name is not found the usual way, so you are free to add or override names in `A` which you do not want to be forwarded to `B`.

Comment: How would you suggest using inheritance differently?  As is, Acid inherits from Compound.

Comment: If `Acid` inherits `Compound` then why do you need to wrap a `Compound` as well? Your code seems to be saying that `Acid` both _is a_ `Compound` and _has a_ `Compound`. That seems incorrect to me.